# Local angular library in an NPM workspaces project

Tags: angular, angular-library, npm-workspaces

I have a local angular library created using `ng generate library utils`.

I then add its dependency to my angular project package.json, making sure to link to the inner lib folder under `utils/dist/utils`, and everything is working as expected:

```
"utils": "file:../utils/dist/utils"
```

When I look at the content of `node_modules/utils` in my angular module I see the content of `utils/dist/utils`.

I'm now refactoring the project to use NPM Workspaces so I can remove the dependency and NPM will install it automatically since it is a workspace.

The issue is that NPM is taking the entire root folder of the library and not the inner `dist/utils` folder and everything breaks.

When I look at the content of `node_modules/utils` in the root folder I now see the content of `utils`.

I get an error in all my imports stating:

```
TS2307: Cannot find module 'utils' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

Is there a proper solution to this issue?

Comment: I had the same issue and this answer was the right thing to do : https://stackoverflow.com/a/73388898/5499650