# NPM Workspaces Typescript unable to find local modules

Tags: node.js, typescript, monorepo, npm-workspaces

I have a NodeJS monorepo set up using NPM workspaces and Typescript. It works fine without Typescript, however introducing TS brings some dependency resolving errors with it. Current directory setup:

```
+-- node_modules
+-- package.json
+-- tsconfig.json
+-- tsconfig.build.json
+-- packages
    +-- core
    |   +-- package.json
    |   +-- tsconfig.json
    |   +-- src
        |   +-- index.ts
    +-- shared
    |   +-- package.json
    |   +-- tsconfig.json
    |   +-- src
        |   +-- helper.ts
```

Running `npm ls` confirms that everything has been symlinked up correctly:

```
monorepoDemo@1.0.0 C:\Users\<user>\Documents\Temp\monorepoDemo
├─┬ @my-packages/core@1.0.0 -> .\packages\core
│ └── @my-packages/shared@1.0.0 deduped -> .\packages\shared
└── @my-packages/shared@1.0.0 -> .\packages\shared
```

I've got a dummy helper function being exported from `helper.ts` in `shared`. Which is being imported into `index.ts` in `core`. The root `package.json`, `tsconfig.ts` and  `tsconfig.build.json`:

```
{
    "name": "monorepoDemo",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node packages/core/src/index.ts",
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "build": "tsc -b --verbose tsconfig.build.json"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "workspaces": [
        "packages\\core",
        "packages\\shared"
    ]
}
```

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "composite": true,
        "target": "es2021",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationMap": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "strict": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true
    }
}
```

```
{
    "files": [],
    "references": [
      {
          "path": "packages/core"
      },
      {
          "path": "packages/shared"
      }
    ]
}
```

The `package.json` and `tsconfig.json` of `core`:

```
{
  "name": "@my-packages/core",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@my-packages/shared": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

```
{
    "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
      "rootDir": "./src",
      "outDir": "./dist",
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "paths": {
        "@my-packages/shared": ["../shared"]
        }
    },
    "references": [{ "path": "../shared" }],
    "exclude": ["dist"]
}
```

The `package.json` and `tsconfig.json` of `shared`:

```
{
  "name": "@my-packages/shared",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

```
{
    "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
      "rootDir": "./src",
      "outDir": "./dist"
    },
    "exclude": ["dist"]
}
```

And the source code of `index.ts` and `helper.ts`:

```
import { helper } from "@my-packages/shared"

(async () => {
    console.log("Bootstrapping from core package")

    helper()
})()
```

```
export function helper(): void {
    console.log("Running from shared package")
}
```

The error I get in `index.ts`:
`Cannot find module '@my-packages/shared' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)`

I assumed it was something related to a missing declaration file, so tried to create one for `helper.ts` but didn't get anywhere

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. I noticed in your package.json files you have index.js listed as your main entry point to both packages but your files are typescript. I'm pretty sure the main file is how imports are resolved for packages so that might be why? You could making your main file "./src/index.ts" instead

Answer (score 15):

The `main` field of `package.json` file is the entry point when other packages (like `core`) imports the package:

```js
import { helper } from "@my-packages/shared"
```

This code will try to look for `@my-packages/shared/index.js`, which does not exist.

When you build the shared package, the built file is at `dist/helper.js`.

Changing the main field to `"main": "dist/helper.js"` made it work. If you are using vscode, don't forget to restart the language server.

[image: has error before change]

[image: no error after change]

For other considerations, like specific compiler options or esm support, consult the document [ECMAScript Modules in Node.js](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/esm-node.html).

Comment: This works with the single top level `helper.[ts|js]` file, but what about whole structured `shared` app or library? Is it necessary to introduce barrel files?

Comment: Nice name. I don't know what a "barrel file" is, but I got this working by creating an index.ts for my project at the root and doing multiple `export * from './someFile.ts';` inside. It's incredibly annoying that all examples of doing this just have a single `index.ts` in the root of each project, so you have to guess the rest.

Comment: In my case, the main path I had specified was relative using `./`, removing the unneeded prefix `./` solved the issue

Answer (score 4):

The project `monorepoDemo` should use the project `@my-packages/core` that is **built**, in your case in the `(sharedDir)/dist` directory.

In order for typescript to find the package `@my-packages/core` when parsing `monorepoDemo` typescript files, you have to specify where this package is located in the `monorepoDemo`'s tsconfig.json file:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "allowJs": true,
  "paths": {
    "@my-packages/shared": ["(sharedDir)/dist"],
```

After that make sure the library is built and the `(sharedDir)/dist` folder created.

If there are several projects that use `@my-packages/shared`, you can create a  single `tsconfig.libs.ts` file that contains all libraries locations, and add an `extends` property into `tsconfig.ts` of projects to `tsconfig.libs.ts`:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.lib.json",
```

Answer (score -1):

You're missing a `src` at the ends of your paths in `references` and `compilerOptioms.paths`.

Comment: The `path` in `references` needs to resolve to a `tsconfig.json` file, which works. (if I ctrl click on it, it brings me to the `shared` `tsconfig.json` file. Tried adding `src`, `src/*.ts` etc but unfortunately nothing seemed to work. I was also restarting the TS server in between these changes to double check